# How to rename/relocate directory on git clone/fetch and preserve the history?

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-subtree

On remote master there is a folder **/config/samples/** (it also contains sub dirs) which contains sample configuration files; these files are good enough to be used in real environment w/o any changes. The application is located in the same repository and can read the files from **/settings/** directory only.

How to make that each clone of the master will rename locally this folder to the desired one AND will keep the history for these files (so If I add file there, it will be placed to the right folder on the master on git pull)?

The symlinks and hardlinks are not available on the filesystem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question properly, but git sees renamed files. If you perform

```
    mv file_orig_name.ext file_new_name.ext
    git rm file_orig_name.ext
    git add file_new_name.ext
    git commit -m "changed file name file_orig_name.ext to file_new_name.ext"
```

they will show as being renamed rather than one disappearing and the other appearing.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no such functionality in git.

For this kind of functionality will have to make use of features of your OS, like symlinks if these where available. In this case there is still a setup process that needs to be run, so tools like Make or Rake could help you to create the folders you want and perhaps checking for changes in them.

Finally, you could consider is to use [git hooks](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) so that your scripts get called on specific events. `post-checkout`, `post-merge`, and perhaps `post-commit` could be useful for this.